# How to automatically update a property which contains file last modification date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I have an entity with datetime property `ImageModifiedDate` which stores image last modification date. If I change the image can this property be updated automatically somehow? I mean can this property be bound to the file (the image) and can it be changed (automatically) when the actual file changes?

I need this in asp.net mvc 3 app, but I think it can also be marked as c# question.

**Edited:** I store images on the filestream, not in the database

Comment: Where does the image reside? On the same server as the ASP.NET application?  How up-to-date do you need to be? Up to the second? When you say, "entity", are you referring to Entity Framework?

Comment: on the same server; would be great that it be up to a second; no, I use Linq2Sql, I meant my model

Comment: Have a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class, for monitoring changes to files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you have a problem in two pieces: updating the last modification date in the database, and knowing that the database has changed, then displaying the changes.

For the first, create a Windows Service or such program and have it use a FileSystemWatcher to watch for file changes. It can then update the database with the new information.

As to displaying the changes in the web application, you can have the application poll via AJAX and just update the HTML that displays the date. This way, you won't have to update the whole page just when a date changes.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to need to have some sort of service going through your images and checking them to see if they have been updated. It would need to do something like this:

```
foreach (var image in dbcontext.Images)
{
    var filename = image.Filename;
    var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filename);

    if (lastModified != image.LastModified) 
    {
        image.LastModified = lastModified;        
    }
}

dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Bear in mind that you have a trade off decision to make. You can have it running constantly, but that will slow down your server. Or you can run it every minute, or every five minutes, depending on how many images you have and how long it will take the process to complete.

Alternatively you could use `FileSystemWatcher`, something along these lines (bear in mind I haven't tested this code, but it's enough to get you started):

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "your path here";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
watcher.Filter = "*.jpg";

watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);


private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: I store images on the actual filestream, not in a database. I have hundreds of thousands of images, if I run it every minute I think it will really slow down the server. Is there other way to do it? Also I wanted images to be updated instantly (if it possibly can be done of course).

Comment: Possibly by using `FileSystemWatcher`? @AlekseiChepovoi see update.